# Why is Heading tag Auto applied to Post data?

Tags: tags, html5

why this heading tag is applied to my article, i mean instead of article showing in paragraph its showing in h4 tag because i applied it to date and it auto applied to my content too.

```
echo '<h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>';
echo '<h4>'.get_the_date().'<h4>';

echo'<br/>';

while(have_posts()): the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;
```

Comment: your <h4> is not closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second h4 tag is again an opening tag.

This

```
echo '<h4>'.get_the_date().'<h4>';
```

should be this

```
echo '<h4>'.get_the_date().'</h4>';
```